# Не могу сделать http запрос к json файлу

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

[image: Структура проекта]

Необходимо из файла log-publishers.service.ts сделать запрос в log-publisher.json А я получаю ошибку в консоли браузера : **GET https://localhost:5001/app/assets/log-publisher.json 404 (Not Found)**
Запрос:

```
getLoggers(): Observable<LogPublisherConfig[]> {
        return this.http.get('app/assets/log-publisher.json').pipe(map(data => {
            let logConfigList = data["logConfig"];
            return logConfigList.map(function (x: any) {
                return {
                    loggerName: x.loggerName,
                    loggerLocation: x.loggerLocation,
                    isActive: x.isActive
                };
            });
        }));
    }
```

Я думаю, что проблема с адресом (я по всякому пробовал), но на всякий случай привожу файл log-publisher.json

```
{
  "logConfig":
  [
    {
      "loggerName": "console",
      "loggerLocation": "",
      "isActive": true
    },
    {
      "loggerName": "localstorage",
      "loggerLocation": "logging",
      "isActive": true
    },
    {
      "loggerName": "webapi",
      "loggerLocation": "/api/Log",
      "isActive": true
    }
  ]
}
```

и класс LogPublisherConfig

```
export class LogPublisherConfig {
    loggerName: string;
    loggerLocation: string;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Файл должен быть размещён в wwwroot. [Static files in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Положил в wwwroot, сделал запрос http.get('log-publisher.json') - та же ошибка. Может я чего-то не понял?

Comment: Я же из страницы.ts делаю запрос, а не из бэкэнда.

Answer (score 1):

в файле tsconfig.json добавь "resolveJsonModule": true в compilerOptions

потом просто импортируй

```
import  *  as  data  from  "./assets/SampleJson.json";
```

Comment: Знаю такой способ, и он работает ( я пробовал), но мне нужно как-то выдать именно Observable<LogPublisherConfig[]> на выход. Как его выдать указанным Вами способом я не знаю.